# How can I manipulate data on a has_many :through Association on ActiveRecords on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The documentation is a little poor in this aspect. If I have this tables

```
 Physicians Table
-----------
id integer
name string

Appointments table
----------------
id integer
physician_id integer
patient_id integer
appointment_date datetime

Patients table
---------------
id integer
name string
```

and this models:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pshysician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :pshysicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

how do I do to insert an appointment on the database? It's not clear at all in the Rails webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite broad question actually. To insert a record in the database you can do one of three things.

1. `Appointment.create(patient_id: 1, physician_id: 1, apt_date: DateTime.now)`
2. If you have an instance of the `Patient` model lets call it `patient` and you want to assign in to physician with `id=2` then

   `patient.appointments.create(physician_id: 2, apt_date: DateTime.now)`
3. If you have an instance of the `Physician` model called `physician` then

   `physician.appointments.create(patient_id: 10, apt_date: DateTime.now)`

Comment: which of these 3 is better?....From what you say I assume it depends on which page I am right?....It is OK to use scaffolding for the 3 models in this case and then rearrange the code at my taste or you would create every entity from scratch?....

Comment: It depends on the context as well as your architecture. For example if the `patient` logins to a system and does the appointment and you have your patient in the session so most probably you will stick with option 2. If the doctor does the appointments then option 3. And if it is a system where you randomly assign doctors to patients for example or you choose the two parties by yourself then you will go with 1. It is all about the parameters passed to your controllers and the context of your application. Good luck!